# setting up the Eclipse for Rcpp/Armadillo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, rcpp, armadillo

I am new to area of writing functions for using in R using Rcpp and Armadillo. I was looking trough the Tutorials and other questions which asked about this topic, but I was not able to find something suitable because most of them were out dated and did not work for me.

I would like to ask for any help with setting up the Eclipse for using Rcpp on Windows 10.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R Project documents all build and tests steps via commands starting with `R` with for example

- `R CMD build`
- `R CMD COMPILE`
- `R CMD SHLIB`

and so on.  Eclipse, as far as I know, prefers `cmake` so you need to write a `CMakeLists.txt` to do what you need.  You will have to duplicate file location searches and all those features R provides for you. I suspect this to be a bit of work.

I did receive a contribution to `RInside` many moons ago so if you in its [inst/examples/](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/tree/master/inst/examples) directory:

```
edd@rob:~/git/rinside(master)$ find . -name CMakeLists.txt
./inst/examples/eigen/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
./inst/examples/wt/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
./inst/examples/qt/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
./inst/examples/mpi/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
./inst/examples/armadillo/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
./inst/examples/standard/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
edd@rob:~/git/rinside(master)$
```

I am not sure if these are still current and working but you could start there.

Comment: My pleasure. You may find some older tutorials too. These days most on-line excitement appears to be about VSCode integration.